# Read and Execute JavaScript from URL on function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a URL that has some JavaScript file, ImportantScript.js:

```
www.PrivateDomain.com/ImportantScript.js
```

I have another URL, www.ImportantBusiness.com, that has some other script file on its page with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    // Code to read and execute ImportantScript.js
}
```

What code do I need for the browser viewing www.ImportantBusiness.com to read and execute ImportantScript.js from the URL www.PrivateDomain.com/ImportantScript.js

Comment: I assume just adding a normal `<script src="...">` tag to the HTML isn't possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with $.getScript(), it shoud do what you want. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following.

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "http://www.PrivateDomain.com/ImportantScript.js"
        script.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete")) {
                        done = true;
                        //call some function when done
            }
        };
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```